# Find int in multidimensional array and apply class in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, ionic-framework

I would like to apply the class `icon-up-selected` when my current user is in the list of `CampaignVotes`.

I tried it like this:

```
<span class="item" ng-repeat="deal in deals"> 
  <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" 
     ng-class="{'icon-up-selected': deal.CampaignVote.user_id.indexOf(12) == -1}">
  </i>
</span>
```

My JSON String:

```
{
  "deals": [{
    "CampaignVote": [{
      "id": "3",
      "vote": "-1",
      "user_id": "4",
      "campaign_id": "39",
      "date": "2016-01-09 17:29:37"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "vote": "1",
      "user_id": "10",
      "campaign_id": "39",
      "date": "2016-01-09 17:36:10"
    }, {
      "id": "8",
      "vote": "1",
      "user_id": "12",
      "campaign_id": "39",
      "date": "2016-01-09 18:06:19"
    }]
  }]
}
```

That does not seem to work, probably due to the fact that `CampaignVote` has its own items. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CampaignVote is an array, so you cannot access the user_id directly.
You could iterate over the array like:

```
<span class="item" ng-repeat="vote in deals[0].CampaignVote"> 
   <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" ng-class="{'icon-up-selected': vote.user_id == 12}"></i>
</span>
```

Also if you have more then one element in deals, you require nested loops.

Comment: the OP wasn't trying to compare to `-1`, they were trying to use `indexOf` to find `user_id` `12`.  In your modified version, you probably want to compare against `12`.  Of course, comparing the `indexOf` to `-1` would only give a true result if `12` *wasn't* a match, which is the opposite of what the OP described....

Comment: Just a small advice. Avoid conditions in HTML. All scope variables are functions and you can use something like `ng-class="getClassName"`. The reason is when your HTML grows and there are multiple condition, HTML becomes very complicated. Ideally try to put all business logic in controller.